# Bundling javafx with install4j

Tags: javafx, install4j

I'd like to bundle javafx 2.1 with my install4j installer, I know I can acheive this by manually depending on the specific .dll and .jar files. But I'd like to do this in the same simple manner that I do when bundling the JRE, is there a way of doing this? If not, will this feature be available soon(or at all) ?

Comment: Is bundling your app as a [Self Contained Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) rather than using install4j an option?

Comment: No, I don't think this is an option because the product consists of three different executables of which one is a service. Thus it must be an installer I believe. But thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pre-made Java 7 JRE bundles that are downloadable in the install4j IDE already include JavaFX, so you don't have to do anything.

Starting with install4j 8.x, you can choose the Liberica JDK provider to get JavaFX for both Java 8 and Java 9+.

Comment: Yes, I just realized this, there is how ever a quirk to this. The jfxrt.jar is placed as you'd expect in the jre/lib folder .. however it is not added to the classpath by default. Thus I just added a step in the installer that copies the jfxrt.jar from jre/lib to jre/lib/ext and this seems to do the trick!

Comment: install4j does not modify the bootclasspath, and the JRE currently does not add the JavaFX runtime, [see the discussion here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2410546). It probably will do so in a later release. Copying it to lib/ext is a good idea for the time being.