# How to bundle javafx with the JRE 14 in install4J?

Tags: javafx, install4j, java-14

This question [was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560913/bundling-javafx-with-install4j) but at a time when JavaFx was integrated with the JRE. Things are different for the JRE14.

Comment: Since you're using Java 14, is trying `jpackage` an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To confirm the answer from Ingo, we are using install4J V8 and find the bundling of JRE and JavaFX JMODS quite straightforward as follows:

1. In Generating Settings-> JRE Bundles **select a JDK release.**  Some (liberica) releases do include the JavaFX modules
2. With the green plus sign on the middle right below JDK release, **select additional modules** (beyond the few that install4J requires.) We include the JRE module set.

[image: install4j V8 download JRE Bundle]

3. Since we are using AdoptOpenJDK, we include JavaFX by way of JMODS, by **adding these JMODS in the Media -> 5.Bundled JRE** panel. Since each media file is targeted to a specific platform, the platform specific JMODS for JavaFX should be added for each media type (*javafx-jmods-14-windows* for windows, unix for unix etc).

[image: install4j V8 media with jmods]

Answer (score 2):

The Liberica JDK still includes JavaFX, so you can use that as a JDK provider in install4j.

Also, you can always download the JavaFX JMODs and add the appropriate JMOD on the "Bundled JRE" step of the media wizard.